# Netezza string searching (fuzzy searching)

Tags: netezza, fuzzy-search, string-search

As far as I know Netezza for string searching only offers two functions 
le_dst(str_expr_1, str_expr_2) and dle_dst (str_expr_1, str_expr_2) as mentioned [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_functions_expressions_fuzzy_funcs.html)

Are there any other more advanced options for fuzzy searching in netezza like oracle has Oracle Text for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from Those two fuzzy matching functions, there are a couple of phonetic matching functions as well. See these:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_functions_expressions_phonetic_funcs.html

I hope that helps in your case :)